# How do I iterate through a dataframe's columns and then run the describe() function on each of these columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, user-interface

What I have tried so far is to iterate through the dataframe columns and then use the control variable in the `df.<columnName>.describe()` function, but this doesn't seem to work...

```py
for (columnName, columnData) in df.iteritems():
  print('Column Name: {}'.format(columnName))
  column_stats = df.columnName.describe()
```

This is the output :

*attr__
    return object.**getattribute**(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'columnName'*

Can someone help me with this rather trivial doubt ...

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
for columnName, columnData in df.iteritems():
    print('Column Name: {}'.format(columnName))
    column_stats = df[columnName].describe()
```

df.columnName is searching for a Column Name ColumnName not the value of your variable